# updating (enable/disable) buttons inside a <p:toolBar>

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

i have a `<p:toolBar>` that contains `<p:commandButton>`
but this toolbar is not put in a form since i am using template
these buttons are executing methods from a managed bean
the methods are excuted correctly and they are updating a form
when i want to enable and disable buttons by clicking on one of them this is not working

example :

```
<p:layout id="layout">  
    <p:layoutUnit position="west">  
      <p:toolbar>  
        <p:toolbarGroup align="left">  
           <p:commandButton type="button" value="New" icon="ui-icon-document" />  
           <p:commandButton type="button" value="Open" actionListener="#{bean.anyMethod}" update="frm"/>  
        </p:toolbarGroup>   
      </p:toolbar>    
    </p:layoutUnit>  

    <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
       <h:form id="frm">
         contents of h:form <p:inputText> and <p:outputText> componenets
       </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>  
</p:layout>
```

my problem is that my `<p:toolbar>` is not in a form and when clicking the **open button** the **actionListener** is working and the `<h:form id="frm">` is updated
but if i want the **new button** when clicked to enable/disable **open button** that is not working
and i cant put the `<p:toolBar>` in a form since my open button is updating the `<h:form id="frm">` and if `<p:toolbar>` is put in a form then  **update="frm"** will give an exception that `<h:form id="frm">` cant be referenced from the toolbar form
any help for my problem please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to disable the *New* button when you click on the *Open* button.

You don't need to put your toolbar into a form, you can disable that button through JavaScript:

```
<p:commandButton type="button" value="New" 
                 icon="ui-icon-document" 
                 widgetVar="disablethis"/>  
<p:commandButton type="button" value="Open" 
                 actionListener="#{bean.anyMethod}" update=":frm"
                 onclick="disablethis.disable()"/>
```

Also try referencing your form with `:frm` in your `update`.

You should also consider changing the `onclick` action depending on your requirements to:

- *onstart*

Client side callback to execute before ajax request is begins.

- *onclick*

Client side callback to execute when button is clicked.

- *onsuccess*

Client side callback to execute when ajax request succeeds.

- *oncomplete*

Client side callback to execute when ajax request is completed.

**EDIT**

If you want to solve this without explicit JavaScript you need to have a flag in your backing bean (as you already discovered), indicating is the Open button disabled or not. Then call the `anyMethod` of your backing bean (which will set that flag inside as you described) and finally update the *Open* button:

```
<p:commandButton value="New" action="#{bean.anyMethod}" 
                 icon="ui-icon-document" update="button1"/>  
<p:commandButton id="button1" value="Open" type="button"
                 disabled="#{bean.disabled}"/>
```

Have the appropriate getters/setters in your backing bean, and set the flag in `anyMethod`:

```
private boolean disabled;

public boolean isDisabled() {
    return disabled;
}

public void setDisabled(boolean disabled) {
    this.disabled = disabled;
}

public void anyMethod() {
    if (disabled) {
        disabled = false;
    } else {
        disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i am thankfull but i dont want to use javascript since the disable of a button depends on the condition to chnge its flag in the bean.anyMethod where the open button is disabled and when clicking the new button according to the business logic of the 
bean.anyMethod the flag will fe changed to false

Comment: i am thankfull but i dont want to use **javascript** since the disable of a button depends on the logic condition to change its flag in the **bean.anyMethod** where when clicking the **new button** according to the business logic of the 
**bean.anyMethod** the flag will be changed to **false**

'<p:commandButton value="New" 
                 actionListener="#{bean.anyMethod}"/>  
<p:commandButton value="Open"
                  update=":frm" disable="#{bean.isOpened}"/>'

clicking **new button** must make 'isOpened=false' then the **open button** must be enabled

Comment: I'm glad that your problem solved now. It wasn't clear to me that you need a no-javascript solution. You could extend your original post, that your condition to disable the button depends on some calculations in your backing bean.